# ngModel undefined everywhere in controller (but it's accessible in template)

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I'm creating a simple form and I need to write a function that would use my input data.

So I'd like to access `object.name` from the below template:

```
.form-group
  label Name
  input.form-control(type="text", name="name", #name="ngModel", [(ngModel)]="object.name")
```

But it's undefined in my controller:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';
// other imports here...

interface IObject {
  name: string;
  description: string;
// other string and boolean properties here...
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo-modal',
  templateUrl: './foo-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo-modal.component.scss']
})
export class FooModalComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() public object: IObject = {} as any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() 
    console.log(this.object.name); //undefined
    console.log(this.object); //undefined as well
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.object.name); //also undefined
  }
```

I've shortened the code and changed naming to make it a clearer example.

Why is it undefined? There's `[(ngModel)]` in the template, so I don't know what else I'm missing.

Comment: The first line in your `ngOnInit` should throw an error. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't have any errors, just empty objects.

Comment: Value inside `ngOnInit()` and `ngOnChanges()` is `undefined` because you have not set it anywhere. What are you expecting?

Comment: oh it is set, I'm setting it in my template and it is accessible and visible on template side

Comment: @VapeKop post a complete example reproducing the problem. As stated before, if this.object was really undefined, the statement `console.log(this.object.name);` would throw an error. And then you contradict yourself later by saying that you jave "just empty object". So, post a Stackblitz, so  that we can understand what **actually** happens.